# How to compare SQL statements for functional equality in Java?

Tags: java, sql, unit-testing

I'm writing unit tests for Java components that generate SQL statements. Using plain old `assertEquals("select col_1,col_2 from a_table", actualSql)` would result in fragile tests. For example: column lists generated from HashSets have indeterminate order; whitespace outside quoted strings is not significant.

The grammar of SQL is not very complex, and I have no need to compare across SQL dialects.  But writing a function that parses SQL into a standard structure is a non-trivial task, and it feels like reinventing the wheel.  Everybody's code is supported by copious unit tests these days :), so there must be a lightweight way to compare SQL.  Can anybody recommend one?

Answer (score 1):

Just excecute SQL queries with testing DB and compare results.

Comment: Not really a solution, for several reasons. My requirement is to create unti tests without a database dependency.

Comment: Sorry - the comment timed out while I was editing it. Not really a solution, for several reasons. 1. I don't think introducing a database dependency qualifies as a lightweight solution. 2. If the statement in question is a delete, there's no result to compare. 3. SQL queries that do not include an ORDER BY clause return results in an indeterminate order, so there is a possibility, albeit slight, that the result of the two queries will differ.